# Filling Google Charts API, getting "Column header row must be an array."

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, charts, google-visualization

I want to fill a Google Chart with data from my function. I also define the header row, but what I get is `"Column header row must be an array."`. How can I fix that? I used the following code.

```
    var data_coll = "";
    var header_x = "['Skill', 'Scoring']";
    data_coll += header_x+',';
    if (skill_info["category"]==="gCSC")
    {
      qcat = 'gCSC';
      for (var x = 0;x<skill_info["data"].length;x+=1)
      {
        ind_name = skill_info["data"][x]["fn"]+" "+skill_info["data"][x]["ln"];
        if ((x<skill_info["data"].length) && (x>0))
        {
          data_coll += ",";
        }
        data_coll += "['"+ind_name+"',"+skill_info["data"][x]["value"]+"]";
      }
      drawChart(data_coll);
```

I also tried  `var header_x = ['Skill', 'Scoring'];` and  `var header_x = array('Skill', 'Scoring';`

drawChart is the function I call to draw the chart with data_call inserting the data for arrayToDataTable() inside.

Update:
I have got WhiteHats solution which seems to be fine (the error is gone). So I now see "Error: Container is not defined".
This shouldn't happen. I use the following structure:

```
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <form class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='elm_emprat pl-3' id="pollingstation"> 
          <div class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label='Basic example'>
            <div  aria-label='Basic example'>
              <div class='btn-group btn-group-toggle' data-toggle='buttons' role='group' id="polloptions">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
      </div>
    </form>   
  </div>  
</div>
```

and I set the following

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('polloptions'));
```

So the element is defined. Maybe I am missing something?

Update 2:
The function to define the Google Chart

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart(data_coll) {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        data_coll
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Company Skill Comparison',
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        width: '100%',
        height: '75%',
        colors: ['#343a40'],
        backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Scoring',
          minValue: 0,
          viewWindow: {
            max:100,
            min:0
          }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Skill'
        }
      };

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('polloptions'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And the huge successFunction where it's all about the gCSC-part.

```
function successHandler(data)
{
      console.log(data);
      var skill_info = JSON.parse(data);
      if ((skill_info.status === 1) && (skill_info.category === "cp") && (skill_info.code === 200)) {
        console.log(skill_info)
        console.log("success loading");                
        //var x,y,dsb,data_coll,ind_name,skill_info,qt,qtx,q_set,q_options='';
        for(var x = 0;x<skill_info["data"].length;x+=1)
        {
        var qt = "<div class='pb-3'><h1 class='display-5' data-panel='cp' id='question_text_"+x+"'>"+skill_info["data"][x]["question_text"]+"</h1></div>";
        console.log(skill_info["data"][x]["question_text"]);
        var option_y = '';
          for(var y = 0;y<skill_info["data"][x]["options"].length;y+=1)
          {             
            option_y += "<label class='btn btn-outline-dark'><input type='radio'  name='options_"+skill_info["data"][x]["id"]+"' value='"+skill_info["data"][x]["options"][y]["answer_value"]+"' autocomplete='off'>"+skill_info["data"][x]["options"][y]["answer"]+"</label>";
            console.log(skill_info["data"][x]["options"][y]["answer_value"]);            
          }
          var q_options = '<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" role="group" id="polloptions">'+option_y+'</div>';
          option_y = '';
          if(x==0)
          {
            dsb = " style='display:block' ";
          }
          else
          {
            dsb = " style='display:none' ";
          }
          document.getElementById("pollingstation").innerHTML += "<div class='elm_emprat pl-3 elm_x_"+x+"' id='pollingstation' "+dsb+">"+qt+q_options+"</div>"; 
        }
      }
      else if((skill_info.status === 1) && (skill_info.category !== "cp") && (skill_info.code === 200))
      {
        console.log(skill_info)
        console.log("success loading");                
        var data_coll = [['Skill', 'Scoring']];

        if(skill_info["category"]==="gCSC")
        {
          qcat = 'gCSC';
          skill_info["data"].forEach(function (row) {
            data_coll.push([row["fn"] + " " + row["ln"], row["value"]]);
          });


          console.log(data_coll);
          drawChart(data_coll);
          qtx = "Top "+skill_info["data"][0]["skill"]+" Skillers @ "+skill_info["data"][0]["name"];
          q_set = '<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" role="group" id="polloptions">'+data_coll+'<button class="sbmt_frm">Next</button></div>';          
        }
        else if (skill_info["category"]==="gRU")
        {
          qcat = 'gRU';          
          qtx = "How do you rate "+skill_info["data"][0]["first_name"]+" "+skill_info["data"][0]["last_name"]+"'s "+skill_info["data"][0]["skill"]+" skill?";
          q_options = "<label class='btn btn-outline-dark'><input type='radio' name='options_"+skill_info["data"][0]["id"]+"_"+skill_info["data"][0]["skill_id"]+"' value='1' autocomplete='off'>0-20</label>";
          q_options += "<label class='btn btn-outline-dark'><input type='radio' name='options_"+skill_info["data"][0]["id"]+"_"+skill_info["data"][0]["skill_id"]+"' value='2' autocomplete='off'>21-40</label>";
          q_options += "<label class='btn btn-outline-dark'><input type='radio' name='options_"+skill_info["data"][0]["id"]+"_"+skill_info["data"][0]["skill_id"]+"' value='3' autocomplete='off'>41-60</label>";          
          q_options += "<label class='btn btn-outline-dark'><input type='radio' name='options_"+skill_info["data"][0]["id"]+"_"+skill_info["data"][0]["skill_id"]+"' value='4' autocomplete='off'>61-80</label>";
          q_options += "<label class='btn btn-outline-dark'><input type='radio' name='options_"+skill_info["data"][0]["id"]+"_"+skill_info["data"][0]["skill_id"]+"' value='5' autocomplete='off'>81-100</label>";  
          q_set = '<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" role="group" id="polloptions">'+q_options+'<button class="sbmt_frm">Next</button></div>';
        }
        else if (skill_info["category"]==="gSC")
        {
          qcat = 'gSC';          
          qtx = "Your most recent skill changes";
          q_set = "<button class='sbmt_frm'>Next</button>";
        }    
        else if (skill_info["category"]==="gPM")
        {
          qcat = 'gPM';
          qtx = "Do you know "+skill_info["data"]["first_name"]+" "+skill_info["data"]["last_name"]+" ("+skill_info["data"]["position"]+" @ "+skill_info["data"]["company_name"]+")";
          q_options = "<label class='btn btn-outline-dark'><input type='radio' name='options_"+skill_info["data"]["id"]+"' value='2' autocomplete='off'>Yes</label>";
          q_options += "<label class='btn btn-outline-dark'><input type='radio' name='options_"+skill_info["data"]["id"]+"' value='1' autocomplete='off'>No</label>";          
          q_set = "<div class='btn-group btn-group-toggle' data-toggle='buttons' role='group' id='polloptions'>"+q_options+"<button class='sbmt_frm'>Next</button></div>";
        }               
        var qt = "<div class='pb-3'><h1 class='display-5' id='question_text_0' data-panel='"+qcat+"'>"+qtx+"</h1></div>";
        document.getElementById("pollingstation").innerHTML += "<div class='elm_emprat pl-3 elm_x_"+x+"' id='pollingstation'>"+qt+q_set+"</div>"; 

      }
      else {
         console.log(skill_info);
         console.log("failure loading");
      }  
}
```

**Edit**

Sample of a one-row output:

```
[["Skill","Scoring"],["Jim","3.00"]]
```

Sample of a multi-row-output:

```
[["Skill","Scoring"],["Jim","3.00"],["Reid","5.16"],["Akshay","6.00"]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the entire data set must be an array,
and each row of the data set must be an array...

the data set should be similar to...

```
[
  ['Skill', 'Scoring'],
  ['name', 10],
]
```

and if you're using javascript, there is no need to build a string,
just build the array directly...

```
var data_coll = [['Skill', 'Scoring']];
if(skill_info["category"]==="gCSC")
{
  qcat = 'gCSC';
  skill_info["data"].forEach(function (row) {
    data_coll.push([row["fn"] + " " + row["ln"], row["value"]]);
  });
  drawChart(data_coll);

  ...
```

---

**EDIT**

it appears the `drawChart` function is being called from google's load statement,
before the `successHandler` function has finished building the content, here...

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart(data_coll) {
  ...
```

since google charts only needs to be loaded once per page load,
I like to load it first, before anything else on the page.
in addition, the google's `load` statement will wait for the document to load,
before calling the callback function.
so this replaces the need for jquery's `$(document).ready` function,
or the standard `window.addEventListener('load', ...` function.

another thing, the `load` statement returns a promise,
which can be used in place of `setOnLoadCallback`.

try loading google charts first, before anything else.
and when the promise returns, then call the function that loads the data and executes the success handler.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {  // this is the promise function to replace the callback

  // call function that loads the data here
  $.ajax or whatever...

});
```

then your `drawChart` function will be called in the success handler,
after the content has been created.

---

note: if you are using the BarChart...

```
google.visualization.BarChart
```

then you do not need to load the `'bar'` package, only the `'corechart'` package.

`'bar'` is for their material bar chart...

```
google.charts.Bar
```

---

**EDIT 2**

since we're building an array of arrays,
no need to include the initial array here...

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    data_coll
  ]);
```

change to...

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data_coll);
```

---

**EDIT 3**

data provided seems to work fine here,
after removing the quotes from the number values...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  drawChart([["Skill","Scoring"],["Jim",3.00],["Reid",5.16],["Akshay",6.00]]);
});

function drawChart(data_coll) {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data_coll);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Skill Comparison',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    width: '100%',
    height: '75%',
    colors: ['#343a40'],
    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Scoring',
      minValue: 0,
      viewWindow: {
        max:100,
        min:0
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Skill'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('polloptions'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="polloptions"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So far it seems good. But I still face issues. Can I check your answer later when I fixed my new issue?

Comment: I probably could need your help. Because for somebody who is not so experienced in JS it's a bit strange. Can you check my updated post?

Comment: I see, can you share the rest of the code that draws the chart, including where google charts is loaded?

Comment: Sure. I have just updated the post. For a better overview, the affected part is the "gCSC"-part.

Comment: see __EDIT__ above, it's a lot, please let me know if I need to articulate better...

Comment: could I approach you just one more time on this? There's an issue that occurred today. Yesterday I usually had one entry and the header which was fine. Now I have multiple ones but no chart.

Comment: you have multiple rows and one header? could you possibly share a sample of the data you're having issues with? --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(data_coll));`

Comment: Done. And thanks again for your help, sorry for asking that much.

Comment: no need to apologize, I'm here to help. I think I found the issue, see __EDIT 2__ above...

Comment: No change, same issue. Tried this before as I wanted to solve it on my own. Tried again.  But the output you'd say was right?

Comment: looks good to me, are there any errors showing in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console. It would give me a hint where to look.

Comment: Btw, I have inserted the output from json-stringfiy into arraytodatatable. Same issue: I see the header and the first row if there's one row. From two data rows on nothing's visible.

Comment: see __EDIT 3__ above, the snippet works fine with the data you provided, after removing the quotes from the number values. I'm not sure what else to look at, do you want to update the question with the latest version of your code?